# expect scripts and old network gear outputs ANSI escape characters

Tags: bash, expect

Afternoon,

I have googled this all day and even attempted other solutions in python but not had any success.

I have some old-ish network gear that seems to have a weird terminal type when you SSH to them, the one where CTRL+h is backspace!

This is causing problems for my expect script than needs to do 3 things, 1) log in 2) escalate privileges (think cisco enable) 3) save the config

Tried to set the terminal type but not sure that vt100 is correct, i doubt it is.  I also added the sleep commands to see if a delay would solve it, no dice.

here is my script so far

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set ::env(TERM) vt100
## Get username
send_user "Username: \n"
expect_user -re "(.*)\n" { set user $expect_out(1,string) }

## Get pass
stty -echo
send_user "Password: \n"
expect_user -re "(.*)\n" { set pass $expect_out(1,string) }
stty echo

## Get list of hosts
set f [ open "hosts.txt"]
set hosts [ split [read $f] "\n"]
set hosts [ lreplace $hosts end end ]
close $f

## iterate host
foreach host $hosts {
        spawn ssh "$user\@$host"
        expect {
                "continue connecting" { send "yes\r"; exp_continue }
                "assword" { send "$pass\r" }
        }

        expect "Copyright (c)" {
                sleep 1
                send "\r"
                sleep 1
                send "en 14\r"
                sleep 1
                send "$pass\r"
                sleep 1
                send "config save\r"
                sleep 1
                send "exit\r"
        }
}
```

Output from script

```
deanmoore@laptop% ./zyxel
Username:
dean.moore
Password:
spawn ssh dean.moore@host1
dean.moore@host1's password:
Copyright (c) 1994 - 2013 ZyXEL Communications Corp.
host1> ^[[47;223R%                                                                                                                                                                                                     
deanmoore@laptop% 7;223R
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Apologies.  Seems I cannot edit the question.

I would like to find a way to compensate for the garbage characters being returned so I can automate some tasks on this kit
    host1> ^[[47;223R%